# how to return data in array using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

good day ;
I have custom data base helper in laravel framework
I have easy question how to `return` data in `array` not in `objects`.
her is my function

```
public static  function  allData($dbName,$tableName,$condition,$data){

            $stattment=
                DB::connection($dbName)
                    ->table($tableName)
                    ->select(['*'])
                    ->whereRaw($condition, $data)
                    ->get();

            return $stattment;

        }
```

next function

```
public static function getDataById($dbName,$tableName,$condition,$data)
        {
            $stattment=
                DB::connection($dbName)
                    ->table($tableName)
                    ->select(['*'])
                    ->whereRaw($condition, $data)
                    ->get();
            return $stattment;
        }
```

Comment: you can use `return $stattment->toArray();`

Answer (score 1):

The query result is a `Collection` object has a `toArray()` method.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-toarray

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has in-built [toArray()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-toarray) method

You can use it like this:

```
public static  function  allData($dbName,$tableName,$condition,$data){

        $stattment=
            DB::connection($dbName)
                ->table($tableName)
                ->select(['*'])
                ->whereRaw($condition, $data)
                ->get();

        return $stattment->toArray();

    }
```

Same goes for the other function:

```
public static function getDataById($dbName,$tableName,$condition,$data)
    {
        $stattment=
            DB::connection($dbName)
                ->table($tableName)
                ->select(['*'])
                ->whereRaw($condition, $data)
                ->get();
        return $stattment->toArray();
    }
```

Now your *$statement* will be displayed as array.